# Bloch sphere representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

Suppose you know that a qubit is either is in state $|+\rangle$ with probability $p$ or in state $|-\rangle$ with probability $1-p$. If this is the best you know about the qubit's state, where in the Bloch sphere would you represent this qubit?

Comment: In your first sentence, are you specifying that the qubit is in a pure state?  See response and comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a homework question, here's a bit to get you started: I'll assume you mean that the qubit is in the pure state
$$
  |\psi\rangle = \sqrt{p}|+\rangle + \sqrt{1-p}|-\rangle
$$
The [bloch sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) representation of pure states can be written as follows:
$$
  |\psi\rangle = e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2)|+\rangle + \cos(\theta/2)|-\rangle
$$
Post more of your work if you're still stuck and need guidance.

Comment: That's not what the question says -- if I'm not mistaken, it says $\rho = p\vert+\rangle\langle+\vert + (1-p)\vert-\rangle\langle-\vert$.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Normalization demands $\langle \psi|\psi\rangle = 1$.  Given my expression for the state, one has $\langle \psi|\psi\rangle = \sqrt p^2 + \sqrt{1-p}^2 = p + 1-p=1$.

Comment: Yes, but the way the question is phrased it talks about a *mixed* state rather than a *pure* one.

Comment: @Norbert: the way the question is phrased, it is simply ambiguous.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch You may be right; I'll ask for clarification from the user...

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Actually it also just occurred to me that the block *sphere* (surface of the bloch ball) is in one-to-one correspondence with pure density operators that have $\mathrm{tr}(\rho^2)=1$, so I'd find it strange if the OP were attempting to specify the mixed state you wrote down given that the question refers to the "sphere" instead of the "ball."

Comment: @joshphysics But it also says "in the Bloch sphere", not "on the bloch sphere". ;-)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Haha ok fair enough; let's see what the OP says.

Comment: The question doesn't specify that the answer should be a specific point on/in the Bloch sphere Ball. I'd answer by a whole disk in the Bloch ball, or by a circle on its surface if the state is pure...